# iOS: "attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]" when creating dictionary

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-literals

I'm creating a custom navigation bar class and customizing it's title attributes using the following code:

```
self.titleTextAttributes = @{ UITextAttributeFont: bariol,
                              UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]
                            };
```

However, when I run the code, it returns the following error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
```

I'm using Xcode 4.6 and running on a device using iOS 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameters of the literals (values and keys of your dictionary) must not be `nil`.

If you prefer a constructor which is less strict, you might consider using `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]` instead.

Comment: That's not less strict, it just thinks the arguments have stopped if a `nil` is found where a key was expected. Notably, if you pass a `nil` object, you'll get the exact same exception.

Comment: @KevinBallard nonsense. what is returned from `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"a", @"a", nil, @"b", nil];`? it stops reading at the first nil object argument.

Comment: Sorry I meant object when I said key (darn flipped method). It can't distinguish between a `nil` object and the sentinel `nil`. Try using `nil` for a key and see what I mean: `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"anObj", @"aKey", @"anotherObj", nil, nil]`.

Comment: @KevinBallard yes, i know what happens if a *key* is missing when `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]` is used. that does not apply to this context because if the framework constant keys `UITextAttributeFont` or `UITextAttributeTextColor` were `nil`... a lot of programs would break. so yes, people use `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]` to short circuit dictionary construction parameters where literals cannot in the presence of optional entries. Literals OTOH, forbid that entirely -- all keys and values must be valid objects.

Comment: Most people tend to think that the `nil`-object-shortcutting behavior is actually bad because it can silently truncate your dictionary.

Comment: @KevinBallard I'm not sure about "Most people" in this case -- never polled. You could infer hesitation/caution from my word choice in the answer. I know a lot of objc devs really like `nil` as a magic or optional value in system APIs and in their programs -- I think it hurts more than helps. That is to say, I very much favor the stricter semantics -- but I've met a lot of objc devs who prefer it lax.

Comment: I switched to `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:`, works better than `@{}` for the time being.

Comment: Got exactly same problem and fix with dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: Thanks.

Comment: This is not a good suggestion, more subtle bugs may arise from using that method, like missing data if for example you would populate a response to a server and send as is. The best action is to check data before inserting into a dict.

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like your `bariol` object is `nil`. You can't store `nil` in a dictionary.

**Edit:**

Actually, are you sure that's the right line of code? Your error references `NSPlaceholderArray`, which suggests it's a problem with a `@[]` literal, not a `@{}` literal.

Comment: @justin: `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:` doesn't use `NSArray`s. It uses C arrays.

Comment: whoops - nonsense returned :) it's still possible that NSArrays are created in the process of constructing the dictionary (or calling another constructor), thus the message of the exception.

Comment: @justin: An `NSDictionary` literal does not construct intermediate `NSArray`s. So unless `-setTitleTextAttributes:` is doing something funky, that's not the case.

Answer (score 5):

This error seems to be somewhere else. It's pointing to an array error at object '1'. In your case you have a dictionary and object '1' is `UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]` which will never be nil.

Comment: yes, for those who come looking to confirm the [<number>] on the exception message, it is the 0-indexed array offset of the failing (nil) object.  Tested with:  NSString *str = nil;
    NSDictionary *foo = @{NSFontAttributeName:str,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:@"booboo" };

Comment: @robm BOOM! Nice one.